# how to remove "wordpress" word from mail sending by contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I don't know how I setup in contact form 7. I just want to remove the word "wordpress" and give my custom name here in mail send by this plugin.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are thinking too much its a simple customization that is given in contact form 7 in **Mail** tab.. You just need to change the content of From : `<your-name>`

I will send you a screenshot hope that works

https://prnt.sc/gtwg8v

Answer (score 2):

try with below code. Code will goes to functions.php

```
// Function to change email address

 function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
 return 'tim.smith@example.com';
}

// Function to change sender name
function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
 return 'Tim Smith';
}

// Hooking up our functions to WordPress filters 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wpb_sender_name' );
```

Comment: can you provide me correct path of this file please

Comment: @ManvendraRajpurohit `wp-content/themes/[your-theme]/functions.php`

Comment: when I add this code my website was gone blank. why ?

Answer (score 1):

add

```
[your-name] <inquiry@example.com>
```

and don't forget to replace example.com with your actual domain name